# Why is my immutable Redux store not the same in UI and test?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm building up an AppHeader component that connects to a Redux store to get its props. Ideally, I'd probably do it different, but decided to use as an exercise in testing a connected component (I'm new to React).

I'm trying to test this component by using redux-mock-store, but when I get it working in tests, the UI fails. When I get it working in the UI, the tests fail.

The `PROBLEM_LINE` in `AppHeader.component.js` below, is where the symptom originates.

When set to `appHeader: state.get('AppHeader')`, the tests pass successfully, but the console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: state.get is not a function at
    Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]`
```

When set to `appHeader: state.AppHeader`, the UI correctly displays "Real App Title" inside of an  but the test now throws:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJS' of undefined
```

---

This seems to be an issue with using Immutable.js structures. If I change both `initialState` variables using plain JS objects, the tests pass and the correct value is displayed. I feel like I must be using immutable incorrectly, or am not getting stores set up correctly with it.

I've read nearly all the posts returned by Google re: testing connected components/containers but most were using `state.AppHeader` or `state.get('AppHeader')` in mapStateToProps, and most except a precious few were more on how to hook up redux and react but not so much testing it.

I tried to forego using redux-mock-store, and creating my own store (i.e. a function with dispatch, subscribe, etc) but that didn't solve any problems and only created new ones. Maybe I need to reinvestigate that if that's a better way in the end.

---

#### src/index.js

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux';

import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import routes from './routes';

const store = configureStore;
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

#### src/store/configureStore.js

```javascript
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';

import * as reducers from '../ducks';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  ...reducers
});

export default createStore(
  rootReducer
);
```

#### src/ducks/index.js

```javascript
import AppHeader from './AppHeader.duck';

export {
  AppHeader
};
```

#### src/ducks/AppHeader.duck.js

```javascript
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';

////////////
/// Actions

const SET_APP_TITLE = 'new-react/AppHeader/SET_APP_TITLE';

////////////
/// Reducer

const initialState = fromJS({  <-- USING IMMUTABLE HERE
  title: 'Real App Title'
});

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case SET_APP_TITLE:
      return state.set('title', action.payload.title);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

////////////
/// Action Creators

export function setAppTitle(title){
  return {
    type: SET_APP_TITLE,
    payload: {title}
  };
}

module.exports = reducer;
```

#### src/components/AppHeader.component.js

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export class AppHeader extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const appHeader = this.props.appHeader;
    return (
      <div className="appHeader">
        <h1 className="appHeader_title">
          {appHeader.title}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppHeader.propTypes = {
  appHeader: React.PropTypes.object
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    appHeader: state.AppHeader.toJS() <-- PROBLEM LINE
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(AppHeader);
```

#### src/components/AppHeader.component.spec.js

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';

import AppHeader from './AppHeader';

let initialState = fromJS({    <-- USING IMMUTABLE AGAIN
  AppHeader: {
    title: 'Mock App Title'
  }
});

const mockStore = configureMockStore([])(initialState);

describe('AppHeader', () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={mockStore}>
        <AppHeader />
      </Provider>
    );
    component = wrapper.find('AppHeader');
  });

  it('renders without crashing', () => {
     expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('shows the app title', () => {
    expect(component.find('.appHeader_title').text())
      .toBe('App Header Title');
  });
});
```

All dependencies were installed in the last day or so, so are the latest version from `npm install`. The app itself was created with `create-react-app`.

Comment: `combineReducers` function expects the state to be a plain object. As soon as your state is immutable data structure `combineReducers` is kind of frustrated. So you need to install this [guy](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable) which knows how to handle an issue.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @Daniel, it's possible. I did a rewrite of this app recently and saw that there was react-immutable installed as suggested by Islam Ibakaev, but don't think I ever saw it in the code and it didn't make it into the rewrite. Outside of that I don't know if this was specifically ever resolved or I just made due and moved on with my life. Sorry.